# Excel VBA - customized SUMIF function

Tags: excel, vba

I have data like below. First column has combination of tags and numbers and second column has values

e.g.

First row: AB value is 10

Second row: Out of the value 20, AB is 10% & PQ is 90%

[image]

As these tags are custom defined for classification, the letter & numbers can be assumed to follow 2 characters each, except if the percentage is 100% there won't be any numbers after the letters (e.g. first row - AB)

If we segregate the tags and their values, it will be like below

[image]

I guess, an enhanced/customized SUMIF function is required to achieve this. Hope someone can give some ideas

What was tried so far:

1. I tried to do the steps in multiple steps, breaking down the tag into columns --> I was successful, but could not figure out how I can multiply the factor and get a summation. This way of doing it makes it hard to port the formula to other worksheets. Need to create additional columns etc. Hence abandon that plan
2. Thought of creating a VBA script to enhance the SUMIF function. Buy doing this I can copy the VBA code to other sheets and use my custom function. If needed the function can be enhanced further. To get some ideas on this plan, I posted this question

Thanks

Comment: What did you already try and what specific problem(s) did you run into? What are the constraints for the values in the first column?  Only 2-character codes or can they be longer?  Numeric values range from ? to ?

Comment: Can percentages contain decimal points?

Comment: So if I'm understanding your sample dataset. IF the LEN = 2, then use the value, otherwise look at 4 characters, applying the right 2 of the 4 as a percent against the value, and do this for every 4 characters in the cell? What happens if the percent is something like 5% or 5.5%? Would it be AB05? Is it possible for there to be something like ABC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to do this in two steps to make it easier to understand.  First step: separate out the percentage factor by each keyword.  Set up a table to the right of your data.
[image]

In the first row are all the codes you want to create sums for.  Underneath it are the various desired percentages for each of your data rows.  We're going to look for what's in row 1 inside what's in column A.  If we don't find it then the element percentage is zero, if we find it but there's no number after, then the percentage is 100, otherwise use the 2 digit number that follows.  Here's the formula in E2:

=IF(ISERROR(FIND(E$1,$A2)),0,IFERROR(VALUE(MID($A2,FIND(E$1,$A2)+LEN(E$1),2)),100))

The first part says if you don't find E$1 inside $A2 use a zero factor.  The rest says to pick up the two digit number after the point you found E$1, but if it fails, use 100.

After copying the formula into all the cells, you can see the above factors.  The rest is pretty easy.  Incorporate the above formula into a sum range, multiplying by the value in column B and dividing by 100.

```
={SUM(IF(ISERROR(FIND(E$1,$A3:$A7)),0,IFERROR(VALUE(MID($A3:$A7,FIND(E$1,$A3:$A7)+LEN(E$1),2)),100))*$B3:$B7/100)}
```

Don't forget to terminate this array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  I got the following results:
[image]

Comment: Note that it's not necessary to retain the formulas in E3..G7, I just kept them there to illustrate the point.

Comment: Have written a solution, not noticing the question had been closed (what is, for me, overnight) - d'oh!

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMaurer, Yes your solution works. Is there possibility to do this without the intermediary step of breaking down the percentage factor ? Hence my question on if we need to have a VBA script or can it be still done using the standard Excel formulas

Comment: Yes, the formulas in E3..G7 are completely independent of the ones in E2 to G2 - they can be erased without affecting the result.  I kept them there to illustrate  the confusing part of the formula.

Comment: Now I understood. Thank You very much @ChrisMaurer. BTW, would like to know what was the quality issue that my question was auto-closed, could not figure it out myself :(